gcloud app deploy and mvn package appengine:deploy generate app.yaml with generic skip_files JAVA 8
I am working on a Java 8 Google Appengine project with a src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml configuration file. I am trying to setup a .gcloudignore file for deployment, however, both deployment commands mvn package appengine:deploy and gcloud app deploy have a stagging phase that creates an app.yaml file with the following line:
skip_files: app.yaml

This creates the following error with the deployment:
ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Cannot have both a .gcloudignore file and skip_files defined in the same application. We recommend you translate your skip_files ignore patterns to your .gcloudignore file. See https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/gcloudignore for more information about gcloudignore.

Ultimately I am trying to setup a Cloud Build pipeline that deploys the appengine on code pushes to the main branch.
I am expecting either an app.yaml with a populated skip_files using the .gcloudignore content, or no skip_files tag on the app.yaml such that there is no conflict with my ignore file.
